# When the size of two finitely generated minimal sets of modules will have same size?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

Let $M$ be a finitely many $R$-module and let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be finitely generated sets of $M$. If both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are minimal, then u**nder what condition**, we have $$|B_1| = |B_2|$$

I am trying like this 
let $R =Z$, $M= Z = 1Z =B_1 =\{1\}$ and $Z =2Z + 3Z$, $B_2 = \{2,3\}$ , so above written condition is not holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the noetherian setting is: It holds if and only if $R$ is local.

If $R$ is local, it holds by Nakayama.

If $R$ is not local, we always find a non-unit $x$, such that $1+x$ is also a non-unit (This is a criterion for a local ring). Then both $\{1\}$ and $\{x,x+1\}$ are minimal generating sets for the $R$-module $R$.